# Micronaut dependency inject not working with picocli feature

Tags: java, micronaut

I created a micronaut project using below command

```
mn create-cli-app micronaut-cli
```

With in the project I created a @Singleton class and I am injecting it into my Command class but inject is not working because object is always null.

My Singleton class:

```
@Singleton
public class ConverterService {
    public String service(){return "good service";}
}
```

My Command class:

```
@Command(name = "mini-java-util", description = "...",
    mixinStandardHelpOptions = true)
public class MiniJavaUtilCommand implements Runnable {

    @Inject ConverterService converterService;
    @Option(names = {"-v", "--verbose"}, description = "...")
boolean verbose;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PicocliRunner.run(MiniJavaUtilCommand.class, args);
    }

    public void run() {
        // business logic here
        if (verbose) {
            System.out.println("converterService :" + converterService);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this class I am getting:

```
converterService :null
```

Please help me why dependency injection is not working.

Comment: I'm not thoroughly familiar with Micronaut, but Spring supports constructor injection, which helps prevent problems exactly like this. I suggest trying that first.

Comment: Please raise a ticket for this on the Micronaut GitHub issue tracker. There’s also a few Gitter channels for Micronaut (not sure which one to use) where people usually respond fairly quickly.

Comment: It may be useful to add some version information (Micronaut version, picocli version, Java version).

Comment: @chrylis This has nothing to do with constructor based injection vs field based injection.  I suspect the problem is that annotation processors aren't enabled in which case, neither DI approach would work.

Comment: @RemkoPopma "Please raise a ticket for this on the Micronaut GitHub issue tracker." - I don't think there is any need for that.  See my answer below.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown If the annotation processors aren't enabled, then constructor injection fails fast and produces more relevant error reports.

Comment: "If the annotation processors aren't enabled, then constructor injection fails fast and produces more relevant error reports" - That surprises me.  It really shouldn't be a compile time error.  That is a bug.  We intend to defer the bean resolution until runtime because the absence of the bean at compile time does not indicate that it won't be there at runtime.  That being a compile time issue is a problem if that is really happening.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the compile time DI complaint and I cannot.  @chrylis can you send a PR tot he project I mentioned in my answer that demonstrates how to reproduce that?  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Alternatively, if you report the issue at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues with a sample app we can investigate from there.

Comment: Its working fine after enabling annotation processing in my editor. I created same project in kotlin and enabled annotation processing but not sure why kotlin project is not working. Here is the link for my kotlin project https://github.com/kpradeep12/mc-cli-test

Answer (score 6):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you described.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/cliinjection.  I pasted your classes into that project:

https://github.com/jeffbrown/cliinjection/blob/87f289f1bb0e46a487b59665743b5bc767efa620/src/main/java/cliinjection/ConverterService.java

```
package cliinjection;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class ConverterService {
    public String service(){return "good service";}
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/cliinjection/blob/87f289f1bb0e46a487b59665743b5bc767efa620/src/main/java/cliinjection/MiniJavaUtilCommand.java

```
package cliinjection;

import io.micronaut.configuration.picocli.PicocliRunner;

import picocli.CommandLine.Command;
import picocli.CommandLine.Option;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Command(name = "mini-java-util", description = "...",
    mixinStandardHelpOptions = true)
public class MiniJavaUtilCommand implements Runnable {

    @Inject
    ConverterService converterService;
    @Option(names = {"-v", "--verbose"}, description = "...")
    boolean verbose;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PicocliRunner.run(MiniJavaUtilCommand.class, args);
    }

    public void run() {
        // business logic here
        if (verbose) {
            System.out.println("converterService :" + converterService);
        }
    }
}
```

That appears to work:

```
~ $ git clone git@github.com:jeffbrown/cliinjection.git
Cloning into 'cliinjection'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 21, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Total 21 (delta 0), reused 21 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (21/21), 53.36 KiB | 1.16 MiB/s, done.
~ $ 
~ $ cd cliinjection/
cliinjection master $ 
cliinjection master $ ./gradlew assemble

> Task :compileJava
Note: Creating bean classes for 2 type elements

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
10 actionable tasks: 10 executed
cliinjection master $ 
cliinjection master $ java -jar build/libs/cliinjection-0.1-all.jar  -v
07:35:30.515 [main] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [cli]
converterService :cliinjection.ConverterService@7fd4acee
```

**EDIT**

It occurs to me that one way to introduce the behavior you reported is if the project was not compiled with our annotation processors enabled.  The most common way for that to happen is if you are running the project directly from an IDE in a context where annotation processors are not enabled.  We cover this in the user guide at https://docs.micronaut.io/1.0.5/guide/index.html#ideSetup.

Comment: Your answer helped me. DI is not working because I not enabled 'Annotation processing' in my editor. After that, its working fine. I wanted to do same thing in Kotlin and created a project 'mn create-cli-app mc-cli-test --lang kotlin' then enabled annotation processing but not sure why DI is not working in Kotlin project. I upload project at https://github.com/kpradeep12/mc-cli-test please can you clone it check why DI is not working in Kotlin?

Comment: your commit helped me. I was using 'val' instead of 'var' thanks for that.